# Ten friends A - J sat around a circular table. E and F always sit next to each other while H and I do not sit together. Number of ways they can sit?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If we make E and F sit, H has 8 ways to sit, and then I gets 6 ways. So, the rest 6 people can sit in 6! ways. Why is this incorrect, and what shall be the correct answer?

Comment: What is the final answer you have for the count? You mention ways for H,I then the others, but not what your final count is. [It's surely more than $6!$ but I can't see what number you think it is. Do you have the answer from some book and are comparing? If so what book?]

Comment: Question: You say E and F must sit next to eah other. So do you count (going around clockwise) E-then-F and F-then-E as two different cases, or as the same case? Also once the doubleton Ef or FE is placed at the circular table there are nine spot unfilled not eight since no one can sit between E and F. [In general T things at a circular table have T spaces between them not T-1.]

Comment: The correct answer is 12 * 7! and I can't seem to understand the reasoning behind the official explanation, so came here. @coffeemath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of ways E,F and H,I sitting together is $7! \times 2! \times 2!$ around a circular table

The number of ways E,F sitting together is $8! \times 2!$ around a circular table

The number of ways E,F sitting together but H,I not together is $8! \times 2! - 7! \times 2! \times 2!$ around a circular table

Comment: Does your method take into account that the table is circular? [So ten different people can sit in only $9!$ ways since a rotation doesn't change the way sitting at circuar table].

Comment: I will edit for circular table

Comment: @LionHeart You're the boss. Thanks. I got the explanation you posted.